# Laravel JetStream get HasRole of user in resource method

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel Jetstream` teams feature and wants to get list of all team members with their role.

following method from `JetStream` can return role of user

```
public function teamRole($team)
{

    if ($this->ownsTeam($team)) {
        return new OwnerRole;
    }

    if (! $this->belongsToTeam($team)) {
        return;
    }

    return Jetstream::findRole($team->users->where(
        'id', $this->id
    )->first()->membership->role);
```

}

When user hits route `/teams/{team}` I would like to response with all team members name along with their role in team so I have created a `TeamResource` like following.

```
class Team extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
    return [
        'id'            => $this->id,
        'user_id'       => $this->user_id,
        'owner_name'    => $this->owner->name,
        'owner_email'   => $this->owner->email,
        'name'          => $this->name,
        'personal_team' => $this->personal_team,
        'users'         => TeamMemberResource::collection($this->allUsers()),
        'created_at'    => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at'    => $this->updated_at,
    ];
    }
}
```

Following is my `TeamMemberResource` which is `User` model

```
class TeamMember extends JsonResource
{ 

    public function toArray($request)
    {
    return [
        'id'         => $this->id,
        'first_name' => $this->first_name,
        'last_name'  => $this->last_name,
        'role'       => //How do I get user's role in this team
        'name'       => $this->name,
        'email'      => $this->email,
        'active'     => $this->active,
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
    }
}
```

Relationship is `User` has many `Team`.

`TeamUser` table has the column `role`.

How do I access role of user in given team?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The neatest way to do this is to define a separate model for a user within a specific team. Then you don't have to figure out which team you're dealing with. That's probably out of scope for this question, though.

Assuming you want to achieve this using the default models, you need to figure out how to tell the "team member" collection which team it's dealing with.

Start by defining [a separate `TeamMemberCollection` resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections). Override the default `ResourceCollection` constructor, and pass the team as a second argument.

```php
class TeamMemberCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public $team;

    public function __construct($collection, $team)
    {
        $this->team = $team;
        parent::__construct($collection);
    }
}
```

Then update the `TeamMember::toArray` method to *accept* a team, and the `TeamMemberCollection::toArray` method to *pass* the team.

```php
class TeamMember extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request, $team)
    {
        return [
            // Other properties...
            'role' => $this->teamRole($team),
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
class TeamMemberCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection
            ->map
            ->toArray($request, $this->team)
            ->all();
    }
}
```

Finally, don't forget to update the `Team` resource to pass the team to the `TeamMemberCollection` constructor.

```php
class Team extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            // Other properties...
            'users' => new TeamMemberCollection($this->allUsers(), $this),
        ];
    }
}
```